# Adobe Illustrator CS5: How can I make sure the distances between all points on two paths are the same?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5

I have just started to play around with Adobe Illustrator.

How can I make sure distance between path are the same in  all of the points.

Please see this image for example: http://awesomescreenshot.com/03bjt5iec

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of off the top of my head:

1) Measure tool

- Under the eyedropper tool is the Measure tool. Select it.
- Open up the Info window.
- Click and hold on Point A. Drag to Point B below it. Make a note of
  the number after the W in the Info window.
- Click and hold on Point C on your first line. Drag to the
  corresponding Point D on the line below it. Look at the number after
  the W in the info window.
- Are they the same? If yes, hooray! If not, move D until they are.

2) Copy

- Turn your second path into a Guide. (View→Guides→Make Guide)
- Copy your first line. Lock it.
- Under Edit, select Paste in Place.
- Move your new line down to where the second line was. That guarantees the path
  is the same shape and all points should be the same distance from
  their corresponding points.

Answer (score 2):

It is so much easier. Don't know if it is new in CS6. That's the way:
Let's say you have two points connected through a line. Just select that line and click once on the measure tool symbol. be aware to open the info palette before and show all options of the info palette. then appears the distance between these two points in the info palette next to the letter "d".

Comment: Explaining *how* the info panel information is useful could improve this answer.